# ¿Por que mi personaje se mueve solo (unity)?

Tags: c, unity3d

Al momento de darle play el personaje comienza a temblar levemente sobre su propio eje de forma irregular y al momento de moverse en alguna direccion el personaje ''cae'' hacia un lado. este es el codigo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: Imagen de como se inclina cuando esta en movimiento o quieto]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Evita utilizar imágenes ya que no todos pueden verlas, agrega tu código con el formato correspondiente para que algún colaborador pueda replicarlo y ayudarte mejor, veo que eres nuevo, date una vuelta por el [tour] y así comprender mejor el funcionamiento del sitio y en [ask].